# 2013 Microsoft Dynamics CRM - Change forms using JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I've got a custom entity that has multiple forms.

To create a new form, this is done via a sub-grid. The user just clicks the plus button on the subgrid. This populates certain fields on the form. I want to be able to change to a specific form, and pass the data that is populated into the fields across.

Currently, I've used the `Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector` library to switch between forms based on when the entity is in create mode. I use this to switch between the forms:

```
   Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get("48faf3de-5b78-4ce9-a5f7-a01222e4e857").navigate()
```

How do I pass the data that is populated when the form is changed?

Comment: You have to tell/show us how you are populating the data & what data. Are you saying after the navigate() the values are missing, this is expected. Can you save & then navigate?

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar things before. Answer for you is to use Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm method. Description how to use it you can find here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_OpenEntityForm

If you want to add fields to be populated you will have to use approach similar to [url addressable forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334375.aspx#BKMK_setValueLookupfields). Here is code you should use to make openEntityForm to work properly:

```
var parameters= {}; 
parameters["formid"] = "guid"; 
parameters["lookupName"] = "guid"; 
parameters["lookupNamename"] = "name"; 
//parameters["lookupNametype"] = "entityName";//populate this ONLY in case when lookup type is 'owner' or 'customer'
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("entityName", null, parameters, null);
```

Comment: Yeah I used that , but i wanted to set a lookup value through the paramaters you set in open entity form but it didnt work. Thanks for your help anyways, just looking at trying different approaches now :)

Comment: It works for me. Can you please provide code you used?

Comment: Ahhh right ok, how do you set a lookup through the xrm.utilitystuff? thanks :)

Comment: I was using: `var lookup = new Array();
        lookup[0] = new Object();
        lookup[0].id = "guid";
        lookup[0].name = "name";
        lookup[0].entityType = "entityName";                        var paramaters = {}; paramaters["formid"] = "guid"; paramaters["lookupName"] = lookup;  Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("entityName", null, parameters, null);`   But it wasnt working

Comment: Updated my reply.

Comment: Typo in parameters (paramaters)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to save the record, so no need to worry about passing the prepopulated field values. Then navigate to the required form.

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
.
.
.
Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get(formId).navigate();
```